# Post Json object data from one controller to another controller in Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a Json object from one controller (one) to another controller (two):

```
{
   "t": "abc",
   "r": '0',
   "o": "",
   "n": "",
   "v": "1",
   "k": "1.0",
}
```

in controller two I want to receive that data:

```
[HttpPost]
public JObject AllReceivedData(Jobject objData)
{ 

}
```

How can I send the Json object from controller one to controller two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it.

```
//Get Data in Json Format
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

//Sent the Request to URL and Fetch the Data in Bytes
var result = client.UploadData("URL", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request));

//Convert into dynamic object to get Json format
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result).ToString());

//DeserializeObject the "obj" Object in Any Model.
```